# GaussianBlur(frame,frame,Size(10,10), 1.0); error: ‘Size’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv, clion, gaussianblur

getting back to C++ after a while and cannot resolve an issue with this error. Please kindly help.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    constexpr int device_id = 0;
    cv::VideoCapture input_stream(device_id);

    if (!input_stream.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open camera" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const std::string window_title = "CT";

    cv::namedWindow(window_title, cv::WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL);
    cv::Mat frame;

    while (true) {
        input_stream >> frame;
        if (frame.empty()) {
            std::cerr << "The camera returned an empty frame, please check the camera" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        GaussianBlur(frame, frame, Size(10,10), 1.0);
        //blur(frame, blurredFrame, Size(3,3));
        //cv::imshow(window_title, frame);
        cv::imshow(window_title , frame);

        constexpr int delay_ms = 15;
        if (cv::waitKey(delay_ms) >= 0) { break; }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

error: ‘Size’ was not declared in this scope

```
GaussianBlur(frame, frame, Size(10,10), 1.0);
```

expected to get GaussianBlur results

P.S. seems like solution is to use cv::Size

Comment: C++ has namespaces

Answer (score 1):

P.S. seems like solution is just to use cv::Size